# How to resolve Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' issue in TSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to iterate the Mui component **MenuItem** by using **forEach** loop but I am getting **Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'** error.
Here is my code snippet-

```
      <TableCell>
        <Typography>expiry</Typography>
        <Select variant="outlined" sx={{ width: '100%', height: 35, borderRadius: 2 }}>
        { groupData.forEach((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.expiry} value={option.expiry}>
            {option.expiry}
          </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </TableCell>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you mean to use `.map` instead of `.forEach`?

Comment: no @NicholasTower I mean forEach only'

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't return anything. If you want to create an array of `<MenuItem>`s, you need to use `.map`.

Answer (score 6):

`forEach` returns void. To display a list of items in JSX, you use the `map` method of the array, which will convert the items of the array into some other form. For example:

```
const squares = (
  <ul>
    {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((value) => (
      <li key={value}>{value}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

[Learn more about lists in react here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

For your case, you can do the following:

```
<TableCell>
  <Typography>expiry</Typography>
  <Select variant="outlined" sx={{ width: '100%', height: 35, borderRadius: 2 }}>
  {groupData.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.expiry} value={option.expiry}>
      {option.expiry}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
  </Select>
</TableCell>
```

Comment: Yes, I did this but I am unable to get any data in {option.expiry}  seems like the statement is not executing.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(groupData)` and see if it is following the interface contract you are expecting i.e, it should be an array with each element being an object which has `expiry` field.